# Model relationships problem in Rails 3 when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I'm having problems with the relationships on a Rails 3 app. In the index view of one of my models I'm displaying a field from another model, and it is working perfectly locally, but when I push it to Heroku, I get the dreaded "We're sorry, but something when wrong." message. When I check the heroku log the error is "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `marca' for nil:NilClass):"

This is the Marca Model:

```
class Marca < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modelos
  has_many :vehiculos

end
```

This is the Modelo Model:

```
class Modelo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :marca
  has_many :vehiculos
end
```

I'm trying to call f.marca.nombre in the Modelo index view, to display the field "nombre" from the table "marca". I have a marca_id field in the Modelo table. The weird thing is that it works locally, and sometimes it works on heroku if I alter the order of the relationship lines in the model. Then after a few pushes to heroku, it stops working again.

I have tried running 'Modelo.reset_column_information' on heroku console.

Any suggestions? Should I do something to load changes in the model?
Thanks!

Comment: I added a few columns in the weekend, and I did a couple migrations. I tried running 'heroku rake db:migrate' before posting, and it's still the same. Why do you ask?

Comment: you might have forgotten to do a migrate which will make some of your methods nil. but it doesnt seem the case now

Comment: what is the f in f.marca? it's the one being call nil, not marca

Comment: If it is the index view that causes the problem, can you post the index action from the controller and the part from the index view that deals with the f variable?

Comment: show code relevant to the line number where error was reported

Comment: f is nil for some reason. Whatever f is .. Probably you executed find_by and got back nil ? Many things could be happening, You will have to append some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view you are doing this `f.marca.nombre`. 'nombre' is a field in Marca. And you must be doing this in you new action of modelos_controller.

```
def new
  marca = Marca.find(params[:id])
  @madelo = Madelo.new(:marca => marca)
end
```

Check marca for nil and whether marca.nombre is set? This is what is throwing the error.

Comment: I didn't have to declare anything in the new action, but I checked marca for nil, and there where some cases where a Modelo didn't have a Marca, so I had to do it like this: if modelo.marca == nil; modelo.marca_id; else; modelo.marca.marca; end. Your suggestion of checking for nil saved me. Thanks!